# Eclipse CDT update/sync project list automatically (to easy "refresh" related project set)

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

**Historical context:**

We have a project consisting of following parts:

- Host application (C++)
- Scripting Engine library (also written in C++)
- A lot of C++ plugins (around 30+)
- A lot of scripts that tie all the stuff together...

From version to version some plugins are added and some are removed.
Till now we used Visual Studio solution (*.sln) to contain all the projects (*.vcxproj) for Host application, Scripting Engine library and plugins (one *.vcxproj per plugin!).
To share sources/projects we use proprietary source control system, and till now once we merged updates from the server (some plugin projects are added and some plugin projects are removed) all the project tree in the VS were refreshed thanks to "reload" feature (no action was required from developer to see and build updated source tree).

**The problem:**

Now our senior management decided to switch to Eclipse CDT/MinGW pair and we faced the issue that Eclipse Workspace is not the same thing as Visual Studio *.sln ...

Now when some plugin project folder appears or some plugin project folders disappears corresponding workspace items do not update accordingly.

Thus from now every developer has to use <strike>File>Import...>General>"Existing projects into workspace"</strike> File/"Open Projects from File System" to add new projects to own Workspace manually once they were added by other developer to the source control.
Also one has to manually remove from own Workspace those plugin projects that were deleted from source control...

This is a great contrast with what we previously had with Visual Studio where "reload" feature **automatically updated project/source tree** (just bacause all the information arrived with *.sln/*.vcxproj from server).

Our first option was to place Workspace\.metadata etc stuff to source control (as we previously did for *.sln files) but "that is not the way how Eclipse Workspace is designed to be used" (this is even not possible just because paths in .metadata\* are absolute and tons of Workspace\* stuff it is not mergeable at all)

**Question:**

Is there some way to automatically syncronize Eclipse CDT Workspace with project set obtained from source control. Like just press some (hidden?) magic "refresh" button (in special plugin to install or something like that) and all the new projects will be **automatically** added to the source tree in the Workspace and deleted projects will also disappear **automatically**, wothout need to use all those "Import" wizards, and withot need to remove deleted projects manually?

May be there is a special "Container" project type in Eclipse to play the same role as *.sln did in Visual Studio or something like that?

May be other options available?... **Overall intention** is not in replacing *.sln by some Eclipse equivalent but to support similar workflow when bunch of plugin projects is managed as a whole and **project set "refresh" to be simple operation** that does not require from each person in the team to manually track projects appeared/disappeared in that set.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at using CMake to generate the Eclipse project files? You can then import those into an Eclipse workspace.

Its not automatic, but if you create separate CMakeLists.txt files for each part, then you can easily comment the include of that part in the main CMakeLists.txt file and regenerate the project files when you only want to load subset of the project.

https://cmake.org/Wiki/Eclipse_CDT4_Generator

Should you ever want to change back to VS or to another IDE CMake can generate project files for that too.

I've personally only used CMake to generate VS-solutions and Unix make files so I can't vouch for how well this works.

HTH.

---

On side note, why did *management* decide that Eclipse should be used instead of Visual Studio? It sounds like a poor decision without factual grounds or impact research prior to the decision being made.

Was it because Eclipse is free? Did they consider what reduced developer productivity costs?

Comment: You are absolutely right, management decide to use Eclipse just because Eclipse is free and because of "why your team is privileged as compared to our other teams that use free tools" political thing... We postponed migration to Eclipse arguing to "reduced developer productivity" issue but now we face that migration problem again. I like CMake approach, but this still does not fully solve the problem as seen by entire team...